# Java Methods and Calling Method Too Many Times

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing

I'm having trouble with Java methods.  This code is supposed to have three methods. Method 1) Enter # of employees. Method 2) Enter # of days absent for each employee.  Method 3) Calculate average # of days absent.  Then, in Main, the # of employees, # of days absent, and the average # of days absent should print.  Clearly, I don't understand how methods work because when I run the code, the user is asked 4x the number of employees and 2x the number of days missed by employees before it provides the # of employees, # days absent and average # of days absent.  How do I change the code so the user only needs to enter the information once?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /** Asks for the # of employees and their days absent using
     3 methods. 1) Requests number of employees, 2) # of days absent, 3)
     Average # of days absent)*/

    int numEmployeeM, numDaysMissedM;
    double averageNumDaysAbsentM;

    numEmployeeM = numEmployee();
    numDaysMissedM = numDaysMissed(numEmployeeM);
    averageNumDaysAbsentM = averageNumDaysAbsent(numEmployeeM,
            numDaysMissedM);
    System.out.println("\n\tTotal number of employees: " + numEmployeeM +
            "\n\tTotal number of days missed: " + numDaysMissedM +
            "\n\tAverage number of days absent: " + averageNumDaysAbsentM);
}

public static int numEmployee() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numEmployee;

    System.out.print("Number of employees in company:");
    numEmployee = keyboard.nextInt();
    return numEmployee;
}

public static int numDaysMissed(int numEmployee1) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int count, numDaysMissed, totalNumDaysMissed;
    count = 1;
    totalNumDaysMissed = 0;
    numEmployee1 = numEmployee();

    while (count <= numEmployee1) {
        System.out.print("Enter number of days missed by Employee #"
                + count + ": ");
        numDaysMissed = keyboard.nextInt();
        totalNumDaysMissed += numDaysMissed;
        count++;
    }
    return totalNumDaysMissed;
}

public static double averageNumDaysAbsent(int numEmployee2,
                                          int totalNumDaysMissed1) {
    double averageDaysMissed;
    numEmployee2 = numEmployee();
    totalNumDaysMissed1 = numDaysMissed(numEmployee2);

    averageDaysMissed = (totalNumDaysMissed1 / numEmployee2);
    return averageDaysMissed;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand well what you wanna do... you only want to show a statistic of the total missed days for all employees or you want to make a register of all employees and the days they work/missed?

Comment: I just want to display the total missed days for all employees, the number of employees, and the average of the missed days for all employees.

Comment: @user3120754 I would like to display the total missed days for all employees, the number of employees and the average of the missed days for all employees from the main method.

Comment: Also, note that you can also define `Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);` once glocally instead of redefining the class in every method requesting user input.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the code to see what's calling what:

```
void main(String[] args)
{
    numEmployeeM = numEmployee();
    numDaysMissedM = numDaysMissed(numEmployeeM);
    averageNumDaysAbsentM = averageNumDaysAbsent(numEmployeeM, numDaysMissedM);
}

int numEmployee()
{
}

int numDaysMissed(int numEmployee1)
{
    numEmployee1 = numEmployee();
}

double averageNumDaysAbsent(int numEmployee2, int totalNumDaysMissed1)
{
    numEmployee2 = numEmployee();
    totalNumDaysMissed1 = numDaysMissed(numEmployee2);
}
```

So when your code executes, it calls

- main

  - numEmployee
  - numDaysMissed

    - numEmployee
  - averageNumDaysAbsent

    - numEmployee
    - numDaysMissed

      - numEmployee

This gives the expected total counts of 1x `averageNumDaysAbsent`, 2x `numDaysMissed`, and 4x `numEmployee`

In `numDaysMissed` and `averageNumDaysAbsent` you're overwriting your input arguments and making them useless

Try removing those lines and it should work as expected

Comment: Thanks.  Your explanation made it so much easier to understand that I'm overwriting my input arguments; thus, rendering them useless. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks, phflack!  I now understand that I was overwriting my input arguments.

Comment: I have a more general question.  In our example above, how does Java know that by the time it gets to the method double averageNumDaysAbsent, the 2 parameters variables numEmploye2 and totalNumDaysMissed1 represent the values from method int numEmployee() and int numDaysMissed(int numEmployee1), respectively.

Comment: When the `main` method calls `averageNumDaysAbsent(numEmployeeM, numDaysMissedM);`, it supplies the two input arguments.  You could use `averageNumDaysAbsent(2, 5);` and it would be valid code, but may not be useful (and would set `numEmployee2` to 2, and `totalNumDaysMissed1` to 5).  I can't find a link that explains it well, but if you post it as a question I'd be happy to answer it (it's difficult to answer as a comment)